# How to remove leading and trailing space in a tag? regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have user-defined tags in the content, and have keyword tags that has corresponding id number on it

```
const tags = ["<i>", "<c>", "<b1>", "<b2>", "<b3>"];
keyword tags e.g. "<key2>", "<key10>"
```

I have to remove the leading and trailing spaces, because I need to split it by word.

---

Here's is my sample content:

```
let content = 
`<b1> <c> "The Modern Amphibians" </c> </b1>
Modern <b>amphibians </b> have a simplified <key2>anatomy </key2> compared to their ancestors due to <i>  paedomorphosis</i>. 
Caused by two evolutionary trends: <b2> miniaturization  </b2> and an unusually.
Don’t think that this term’s work will be <key23> a piece of cake </key23>`
```

The expected output would be (leading & trailing space(s) removed)

```
let output = 
`<b1><c>"The Modern Amphibians"</c></b1>
Modern <b>amphibians</b> have a simplified <key2>anatomy</key2> compared to their ancestors due to <i>paedomorphosis</i>. 
Caused by two evolutionary trends: <b2>miniaturization</b2> and an unusually.
Don’t think that this term’s work will be <key23>a piece of cake</key23>`
```

---

I have tried to make my own regex, starting with the `c` tag but I'm not sure if this is proper, since I just need only to remove the spaces, but my regex is including the tag.

```
const customRegex = \((<c>\s)|(\s<\/c>))\g.
```

Someone can help. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [`(<[^<>\/]+>)\s+|\s+(<\/[^<>]+>)`](https://regex101.com/r/ivda4b/1/).

This ensures to only remove spaces either after an opening tag (e.g. `<s>`) or before a closing tag (e.g. `</s>`)

```js
const regex = /(<[^<>\/]+>)\s+|\s+(<\/[^<>]+>)/g;

const content = 
`<b1> <c> "The Modern Amphibians" </c> </b1>
Modern <b>amphibians </b> have a simplified <key2>anatomy </key2> compared to their ancestors due to <i>  paedomorphosis</i>. 
Caused by two evolutionary trends: <b2> miniaturization  </b2> and an unusually.
Don’t think that this term’s work will be <key23> a piece of cake </key23>`;

console.log(content.replace(regex, '$1$2'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex `/\s*(<.*?>)\s*/g`

[image]

```js
let content = `<b1> <c> "The Modern Amphibians" </c> </b1>
Modern <b>amphibians </b> have a simplified <key2>anatomy </key2> compared to their ancestors due to <i>  paedomorphosis</i>. 
Caused by two evolutionary trends: <b2> miniaturization  </b2> and an unusually.
Don’t think that this term’s work will be <key23> a piece of cake </key23>`;

const result = content.replace(/\s*(<.*?>)\s*/g, "$1");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: and does this remove newline?

Comment: It means that we take only part of string in brackets excluding everything else that passed in this regexp

Comment: In the regex part I've grouped using `(` and `)`, So what it does is It will get that group from the match and repalce it with only the text that is inside `(` and `)`.

Comment: Yup `\s*` will select any white space character either It would be `space`,  `Tab`, or `new Line` etc

Comment: ohh no. it should not. my bad i forgot to put that in the description.

Answer (score 1):

```
let output = content.replaceAll(/(\s)?(\<\/?\w+\>)(\s)?/g, '$2')
```

This should work

Comment: the closing tag sir does not work.

Comment: Sorry, edited, try now

Answer (score 1):

Your RegEx approach is correct, and here's a feature that'll help: [$1..$9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n)

This feature allows you to "capture" specific parts of a RegExp you matched and reference it when replacing:

```
const regex = /(/w+)/s+(/w+)/;
const string = "John Smith";

string.replace(regex, "$2, $1)); //" Smith, John"
```

To use it in your case, we'll need a regex that would match any tag and replace it with a no-whitespace version:

```
const regex = (<.+>)\s+(<.+>)/g;
const string = "<b1> <c> abc </c> </b1>";

string.replace(regex, "$1$2");
```